# What French movie featured a character repeatedly sent back to a fantasy land?

Tags: time-travel, story-identification, movie

I watched a French movie that must have been made within the last 5 years. The main character was frequently pulled back and forth between the present time, to a medieval land.

- The main character restored paintings.
- He lost his job when his studio flooded.
- When time traveling, he was sucked through the floor or couch.
- He frequently returned to the present day, and researched how to battle or engineering skills.
- The main character eventually became an emperor of the medieval land.

Does anyone know what film this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Les Deux Mondes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0808230/) with Benoit PoelVoorde.

The "sucked" through the floor image scene:
[image]

The French Synopsis on [WikiPedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Deux_Mondes_(film,_2007)):

> Dans un monde parallèle à trois Soleils, dans le village de Bégameni,
>   une petite tribu vit sous l'oppression d'un tyran nommé Zotan. Elle
>   attend depuis longtemps que la prophétie se réalise et qu'un sauveur,
>   venu d'un autre monde, vienne leur redonner leur liberté.
>
> Au même moment, à Paris, dans notre monde, Rémy Bassano est un simple
>   restaurateur d'œuvres d'art discret et sans histoires. Il est marié à
>   Lucile avec laquelle il a eu deux enfants.
>
> Un jour, alors que son atelier se retrouve complètement inondé et
>   qu'il cherche désespérément à sauver tout ce qui peut l'être, il est
>   aspiré et se retrouve projeté à Bégameni. Ce premier passage vers le
>   monde parallèle n'est que de courte durée. Et ce n'est que le début de
>   ses problèmes car sa femme va bientôt lui annoncer qu'elle le quitte ;
>   son assureur lui annonce qu'il n'est pas couvert pour les dégâts
>   constatés, etc. Rejeté de tous, il part chercher un peu de réconfort
>   chez ses parents mais personne ne s'intéresse à ses malheurs et c'est
>   là, en allant chercher du café pour ses frères et sœurs, qu'il se fait
>   aspirer dans le sol et se retrouve de nouveau à Bégameni... où il est
>   accueilli comme le libérateur tant espéré...

More or less:
The is a tyran named Zotan on a parallel word with 3 suns, a restoring paintor get into that world, accomplishing the prophecy and beating the Zotan.

From what I remember, he switches between the two words to get ideas (technologies, looking for historic strateges, etc.), and at some point after beating Zotan, get a "tyran" himself...